# Comparing two sets of std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, compare, std, stdset

I am trying to compare two sets of C++11 `weak_ptr` using GCC 4.7.2. The code below shows the smallest possible sample reproducing the error:

```
std::set<std::weak_ptr<int>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<int> > > set1;
std::set<std::weak_ptr<int>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<int> > > set2;

bool result = (set1 == set2);
```

Trying to compile the above results in a long list of errors, of which the following is the first actual error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:791:6: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first1.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::weak_ptr<int> >() == __first2.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::weak_ptr<int> >()’
```

Due to the transient nature of `weak_ptr`, is comparing an entire set of them just not possible?

**Update:**

One suggestion is to use:

```
bool result = !((set1 < set2) || (set2 < set1))
```

This results in:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:882:6: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__first1.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::weak_ptr<int> >() < __first2.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::weak_ptr<int> >()’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since weak_ptr doesn't support '==', but in this case you can use the comparison operator of the set try:

```
bool result = !(std::lexicographical_compare(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                                         set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                         set1.value_comp()) ||
                std::lexicographical_compare(set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                         set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                                         set1.value_comp()));
```

This will test for equivalence, not equality.  And it lacks a certain... clarity.

Comment: I edited my question with a comment on your initial suggestion. I noticed you updated the answer, and I will definitely give it a try. I will leave the original edit for educational purposes.

Comment: Also, I thought that since I specified std::owner_less as the comparison operator it shouldn't matter whether or not weak_ptr implements '=='?

Comment: @Hans: Yeah, I realized after typing it that it's going to fall through to 'operator <', which has the same problem.  So changed it to the manual version, which can use the specified comparison operator.  Also, my first edit had the spelling a bit off :)

Comment: @Hans: The issue is that the container requirements specify that the '==' operator uses 'std::equal' and '<' uses 'std::lexicographical_compare', but both of those default to using the underlying operator.  I would think `std::set` should use the ordering specified by the set, but that's not what it does