# Compare connection_hdl (weak_ptr) for equality

Tags: c++, comparison, weak-ptr, websocket++

I need to compare two [websocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) [connection_hdl](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/883410bb7723ed4cfa458b70e4ed50f94490e147/websocketpp/impl/endpoint_impl.hpp#L50-52):

```
// Create a weak pointer on the heap using that shared_ptr.
// Cast that weak pointer to void* and manage it using another shared_ptr
// connection_hdl hdl(reinterpret_cast<void*>(new connection_weak_ptr(con)));
```

I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12301916/1382306)

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool equals(const connection_hdl<T>& t, const connection_hdl<U>& u)
{
    return !t.owner_before(u) && !u.owner_before(t);
}
```

but the compiler complains that `connection_hdl is not a template`.

Can the above code be modified to compare connection_hdls?  connection_hdls can be used with containers by using owner_less, so in my inexperience it stands to reason that ownership could be used for comparison.

The only other related [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13960089/1382306) I can find is for comparing sets of weak_ptrs

```
bool result = !(std::lexicographical_compare(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                                     set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                     set1.value_comp()) ||
            std::lexicographical_compare(set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                     set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                                     set1.value_comp()));
```

which seems to be close to my needs, but I can't be sure or rework that code to suit my intent because of my inexperience.

How can two connection_hdls be compared for equality?

### is this safe?

I modified the first code to this

```
bool connections_equal(connection_hdl t, connection_hdl u)
{
    return !t.owner_before(u) && !u.owner_before(t);
}
```

and it compiles.  Is this safe aside from the weak_ptr emptiness caveat?  My inexperience prevents me from determining exactly while my limited experience tells me that just because it compiles, doesn't mean it will work as expected.